# How Do I Analyse a Java Core Dump?

Tags: java, linux, debugging, gdb, coredump

I have several legacy Java webapps in production running in Tomcat on RHEL6 using the latest Oracle Java Server JRE (1.8.0_91). Over the last few weeks, I've had a total of 7 JVM crashes over 4 instances with no obvious pattern of time or which instance crashes. In order to try figure out the cause, I enabled core dumps.

With the latest crash a core dump was produced, however I can't seem to get any information through the standard Java tools like jstack and jmap:

```
[root@c6e6c1b0b90e core-dump]# jstack -J-d64 /usr/jdk/jdk1.8.0_91/bin/java core.24182 
Attaching to core core.24182 from executable /usr/jdk/jdk1.8.0_91/bin/java, please wait...
Error attaching to core file: Can't attach to the core file
sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.DebuggerException: Can't attach to the core file
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.linux.LinuxDebuggerLocal.attach0(Native Method)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.debugger.linux.LinuxDebuggerLocal.attach(LinuxDebuggerLocal.java:286)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.HotSpotAgent.attachDebugger(HotSpotAgent.java:673)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.HotSpotAgent.setupDebuggerLinux(HotSpotAgent.java:611)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.HotSpotAgent.setupDebugger(HotSpotAgent.java:337)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.HotSpotAgent.go(HotSpotAgent.java:304)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.HotSpotAgent.attach(HotSpotAgent.java:156)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool.start(Tool.java:191)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.Tool.execute(Tool.java:118)
    at sun.jvm.hotspot.tools.JStack.main(JStack.java:92)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at sun.tools.jstack.JStack.runJStackTool(JStack.java:140)
    at sun.tools.jstack.JStack.main(JStack.java:106)
```

I have limited success with gdb, in that I can inspect the backtrace and frame but debug symbols are not available and there doesn't seem to be much information available to point to the source of the issue:

```
(gdb) bt
#0  0x00000036186325e5 in raise () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x0000003618633dc5 in abort () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#2  0x00007fe7462f8aa5 in os::abort(bool) () from /usr/jdk/jdk1.8.0_91/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#3  0x00007fe746497593 in VMError::report_and_die() () from /usr/jdk/jdk1.8.0_91/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#4  0x00007fe7462fe2cf in JVM_handle_linux_signal () from /usr/jdk/jdk1.8.0_91/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#5  0x00007fe7462f4a63 in signalHandler(int, siginfo*, void*) () from /usr/jdk/jdk1.8.0_91/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#6  <signal handler called>
#7  0x00007fe745f9d655 in G1ParScanThreadState::copy_to_survivor_space(InCSetState, oopDesc*, markOopDesc*) () from /usr/jdk/jdk1.8.0_91/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#8  0x00007fe745f9e20b in G1ParScanThreadState::trim_queue() () from /usr/jdk/jdk1.8.0_91/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#9  0x00007fe745f78af7 in G1ParEvacuateFollowersClosure::do_void() () from /usr/jdk/jdk1.8.0_91/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#10 0x00007fe745f84623 in G1ParTask::work(unsigned int) () from /usr/jdk/jdk1.8.0_91/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#11 0x00007fe7464b762f in GangWorker::loop() () from /usr/jdk/jdk1.8.0_91/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#12 0x00007fe7462f9f78 in java_start(Thread*) () from /usr/jdk/jdk1.8.0_91/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
#13 0x0000003618a07aa1 in start_thread () from /lib64/libpthread.so.0
#14 0x00000036186e8aad in clone () from /lib64/libc.so.6

(gdb) frame 7
#7  0x00007fe745f9d655 in G1ParScanThreadState::copy_to_survivor_space(InCSetState, oopDesc*, markOopDesc*) () from /usr/jdk/jdk1.8.0_91/jre/lib/amd64/server/libjvm.so
(gdb)
```

So my questions are:

1. How can I use jstack/jmap to analyse the core dump?
2. Can I dig in further with gdb? (It's not my forte)
3. This feels like a JVM bug to me. How can I confirm that?

Comment: My specific case seems to be related to this JDK bug: https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8143310 which indicates that the JVM segfaults due to corruption in the heap. Sadly, I'm no closer to finding the cause of the crash, nor how to analyze the resulting core dump